# Devanagari fonts displayed improperly in Chromium

Tags: fonts, chromium

I cant view [Devanagari (Marathi/Hindi)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) fonts properly in:

`Chromium 7.0.531.0 (60146) Built on Ubuntu 9.04, running on Ubuntu 10.04`

The same is at my home, running 10.04. Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, some text overlaps the other. I have not changed any settings, its the default. At first I thought Wine was responsible for screwing up the fonts, but on a different machine with a different version, the same problem occurs, so I am blaming Chromium for the problem. Any ideas how to get it working?

Comment: I don't knwo how to fix your problem, but I have ecnountered Devanagari "aberrations" in the `gnome-terminal` (no problems in `konsole`)..  Here is a link regarding Canonical's [Charset project](http://design.canonical.com/2010/09/charactersets/).. Devanagari is mentiond towards the end of the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known but unfixed bug in Chromium (and Chrome). The bug causes complex scripts including Devanagari and Thai to position combining marks incorrectly.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43951

Comment: This happens also in Firefox, but the situation is never so bad as I can see the screenshot of that bug

Comment: It's possible a font may render poorly generally, but this specific bug where the maatraa are positioned wildly to the left is specific to Chromium/Chrome, specifically their Webkit engine.

Answer (score 1):

I see that Devanagari fonts are displayed properly when viewed in big font size (14-16) but they start overlapping when the size is 8-9.

I think the problem has to do with font as they themselves are responsible for kerning.